# Ruby hash exclude?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have to check for some string in hash

```
 h = {'a'=>'firsthaha','b'=>'sjdh'}
```

it's work:

```
hash.select { |_,v| v.to_s.downcase.include? 'first' }.keys
```

but how to realize vice versa include?

```
hash.select { |_,v| v.to_s.downcase.????? 'first' }.keys
```

without using active-support exclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hash.select { |_,v| !v.to_s.downcase.include? 'first' }.keys
#or

hash.reject { |_,v| v.to_s.downcase.include? 'first' }.keys
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `!` to negate the condtion:

```
h.select { |_,v| ! v.to_s.downcase.include? 'first' }.keys
```

Comment: Welcome!  I did not know about reject method, thanks to @steenslag answer - I learned something new